How can I configure WSL2 networking settings to access an Azure Private Endpoint?
I have an Azure key vault resource sat on a Private Endpoint that I cannot access when running my project on WSL2 (it works fine on Windows). I've tried updating the config files (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl-config) with no success. Is there a way to configure the WSL network settings to get on the private link?
This is my error message:
azure.core.exceptions.HttpResponseError: (Forbidden) Public network access is disabled and request is not from a trusted service nor via an approved private link.
Caller: xxx
Vault: keyvault-xxx
Code: Forbidden
Message: Public network access is disabled and request is not from a trusted service nor via an approved private link.
Caller: xxx
Vault: keyvault-xxx
Inner error: {
    "code": "ForbiddenByConnection"
}

Thanks
